# Importing or exporting data to & from Excel to Oracle database

Tags: excel, oracle10g

I am using SQLTools 1.5 for writing Oracle SQL scripts. I want to import data from Excel file to Oracle database. How can I do it?

Also how can I export data from Oracle database to Excel file?

Comment: Frankly, you might find it easiest to write an Excel VBA script (or a standalone VB.Net program running on the same PC as Excel), and import from Oracle.  
Microsoft/PC client tools are typically much, much easier to use.  IMHO...

Comment: @ Paulsm4, thank you for the suggestion. but I have very little knowledge of VBA or VB.Net program.

Comment: Trust me - there's probably an order of magnitude difference between the effort of getting something working in MS Excel or MS VB.Net, than using SQLTools.  IMHO...

Comment: ok I'll try it. Thank You. if any problem occurs I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Tools supports importing data from Excel file to Oracle. You could use Oracle's SQL Developer to import data to your database from Excel file.

Jeff Smith explains in his [blog post](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/) how you can do so

> - Right click  on Table –> Import Data
> - Select your file
> - Mind the headers! Does your Excel file have column headers? Do we want to treat those as a row to the table? Probably not. The default
>     options take care of this.
> - Choose the Excel columns to be imported
> - Tell SQL Developer what columns in the spreadsheet match up to what columns in the Oracle table.
> - Hit the ‘verify’ button. Fix any mistakes.
> - Everything looks right! Click on the ‘Finish’ button.
> - Verify the import look at your new table data

You can do the reverse from SQL Developer as well, just right click the table & select Export.

Answer (score 0):

check this, it may help

WebUtil: How to Read an Excel file into an Oracle Form

https://sites.google.com/site/craigsoraclestuff/oracle-forms-webutil/read-excel-into-forms

Answer (score 0):

```
Below sniplet works...

Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.IO
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oraConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using conn As New OracleConnection(connString)
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "select Doc_name,Doc_id from Document;"
            conn.Open()
            Using oda As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn)
                oda.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
        'exportTOExcel
        savetoXcel(dt, dt.Rows.Count)

    End Sub

    Private Sub savetoXcel(dt As DataTable, rows As Int64)
        Dim appXL As Excel.Application
        Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
        Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim raXL As Excel.Range
        ' Start Excel and get Application object.
        appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appXL.Visible = True
        ' Add a new workbook.
        wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Add
        shXL = wbXl.ActiveSheet
        ' Add table headers going cell by cell.
        shXL.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Document ID"
        shXL.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Document Name"
        Console.WriteLine("rows:" + rows.ToString)
        ' Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
        With shXL.Range("A1", "B1")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
        End With
        ' Create an array to set multiple values at once.
        Dim students(rows, 2) As String
        Dim i As Int32 = 0
        For Each Dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            students(i, 0) = Dr.Item(0)
            students(i, 1) = Dr.Item(1)
            i = i + 1
        Next

        Dim BRange As String = "B" + rows.ToString
        'Console.WriteLine("BRange:" + BRange)
        shXL.Range("A2", BRange).Value = students

        'AutoFit columns A:D.
        raXL = shXL.Range("A1", "B1")
        raXL.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        ' Make sure Excel is visible and give the user control
        ' of Excel's lifetime.
        appXL.Visible = True
        appXL.UserControl = True
        'Export to excel
        wbXl.SaveAs(Filename:="d:\Db_report.xls", FileFormat:=50, ReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
        ' Release object references.
        raXL = Nothing
        shXL = Nothing
        wbXl = Nothing
        appXL.Quit()
        appXL = Nothing
        Exit Sub

    End Sub
End Module
```